# Trying to query table with multiple filters

Tags: mysql, django

I am trying to add functionality so a user can select multiple browse filters for a set of items on my site (SDKs).  The code that I have returns SDKs that match any of the filter tags.  How do I ONLY show the SDKs that match ALL of the tags?

```
models.py

class AppSdks(models.Model):
    sdk_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    sdk_type = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    company_url = models.URLField(max_length=1024)
    logo = models.URLField(max_length=1024)
    description = models.TextField()
    ios = models.BooleanField()
    android = models.BooleanField()


class AppSdksTags(models.Model):
    sdk = models.ForeignKey(AppSdks)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=128)

views.py
if request.method=="POST":
    all_tags = request.POST.getlist('filter_tags')
    for each_sdk in sdks:

    results=[]
    sdk_list=[]
    sdks = AppSdks.objects.all()
    for each_tag in all_tags:
        sdks = AppSdksTags.objects.filter(tag=each_tag).values_list('sdk',flat=True).distinct()
        for each_sdk in sdks:
            if each_sdk not in sdk_list:
                sdk_list.append(each_sdk)
    for each_sdk in sdk_list:
        sdk = AppSdks.objects.get(id=each_sdk)
        results.append(sdk)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consecutive `filter` clauses.

```
sdks = AppSdks.objects.all()
for each_tag in all_tags:
    sdks = sdks.filter(appsdkstags__tag=each_tag)
```

That will end up with a single queryset, in which each AppSdks instance has all the required tags.

Comment: This is also almost indefinitely more efficient.

Comment: Tag isn't a field in AppSdks.

"Cannot resolve keyword 'tag' into field. Choices are: android, appsdkstags, company_url, description, id, ios, logo, sdk_name, sdk_type"

Comment: sdks = sdks.filter(appsdkstags__tag=each_tag)